# changing date format in php laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel, date

view

```
<input type="time" class="form-control has-feedback-right"    name="birthtime" id="inputSuccess2" >
```

controller

```
$add->BTime=$request->input('birthtime')->format('H:i');
```

(It showing error doesn't save to db ,I think error in format .How can
 i solve)

Answer (score 0):

`$request->input('birthtime')` is not carbon object so you can't format the date. First you have to convert it into carbon object then it will work. laravel uses carbon to manipulate date and time.Either you can use carbon or default PHP way.

Using PHP Date function
    date('H:i',strtotime($request->input('birthtime')))

Carbon

```
echo Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', $request->input('birthtime'))->toDateTimeString();
```

Comment: how to include carbon in laravel? @Sourav

Comment: The Carbon Package is already is added by Laravel. you have to import carbon package in your file by using below syntax. use Carbon\Carbon;

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast your date and make a Carbon instance with it before:

```php
use Carbon\Carbon;

// the rest of your code

    $add->BTime = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', $request->input('birthtime'));
```

This will work if your `BTime` column of your table is one of `DateTime`, `timestamp` or similiar.

In case it's just a `string`, convert it to that type before: (as @Sourav mentioned)

```php
use Carbon\Carbon;

// the rest of your code

    $add->BTime = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', $request->input('birthtime'))->toDateTimeString();
```

Comment: It should, I always use that on production. Review your code, the error must lay elsewhere. PD: Paste the error or the rest of the involved code so someone can help you.